# Length of light burst of concentrated emission from hydrogen bomb in outer space

Tags: visible-light, nuclear-engineering, x-rays, interstellar-travel

Imagine a large hydrogen bomb in outer space. Behind it is a huge mylar parabolic mirror. (Aimed anywhere, for instance at a star system we want to communicate with.)

The bomb is placed in the focus point of the mirror, such that the mirror will produce a collimated beam.

Obviously, the mirror will vaporize almost instantly, so the question is, for how long duration will the light be collimated?

Comment: IDK, but consider that a lot of the immediate "light" from a hydrogen bomb explosion will be X-rays. Your mylar film won't reflect much of that. Most of the visible light of a nuclear weapon explosion in Earth's atmosphere comes from air that has been heated to incandescence after absorbing those X-rays.

Comment: @SolomonSlow can the device be equipped with a casing that converts xray to photons? Or a thin layer of something in front of the mylar which converts xray to higher wavelengths?

Comment: I wouldn't know how to design such a thing, but a nuclear weapon basically is a device that creates an enormous but brief pulse of heat. If you can use that to heat some body of... whatever to the correct temperature (say, 3000K to 5000K) then the black-body radiation from that whatever will fall into the range that you're looking for. But,...

Comment: ...I haven't done the math (I'll leave that up to you) but, trying to send a signal with 5000K black-body radiation when you're standing right next to a vastly larger source of 5000K radiation (i.e., our Sun) could be somewhat of a challenge.

Comment: @SolomonSlow but you have to do the math. The visible portion a 100 MK device is much brighter (per area, per solid angle) than the visible part of a 5775K star.